# Как умножить каждое значение в массиве на 2 через For... of

Tags: javascript, массивы, for

В JS как умножить каждое значение в массиве на 2 через For... of
Вот пример.

```
let number = [12, 22, 33]

for (const numbers of number) {
    numbers = numbers * 2
}
```

Как видно, у меня тут ошибка, и не пойму где, помогите сделать, пожалуйста

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: Ну так вам надо полученный результат сохранять обратно в массив

Comment: А зачем for of?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо добавить новую переменную, которая будет отвечать за текущий индекс массива, а внутри цикла for of присваивать элементу массива новый результат

```js
let number = [12, 22, 33]

let i = 0;
for (const numbers of number) {
  number[i++] = numbers * 2;
}

console.log(number);
```